# Add to Home Screen Pop up when website open in mobile browser not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, mobile-website

I want to implement add to home functionality for our web application so that user can use the application from mobile (Android/IOS).

The problem is that `deferredPrompt` is `undefined` and `window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt')` is not getting executed on the mobile device.

What can be done here? I already tried [pitchwall](https://blog.pitchwall.co/how-to-add-add-to-homescreen-popup-in-web-app-99d5237fabff) solution and it also not worked.

```js
{
  "name": "DocPro DMS",
  "short_name": "DMS",
  "description": "Document Management System",
  "start_url": "URL",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#2196F3",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "Content/dist/img/favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "favicon"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
var deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  deferredPrompt = event;
});

alert(deferredPrompt)

if (deferredPrompt) {
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  
  deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
}
```

Comment: SO, this question gets marked as duplicate and I don't understand how. both the questions are completely different from each other.

Comment: No they are the same. Your `deferredPrompt` is only set after `beforeinstallprompt` has fired, yet your other code (outside of the `window.addEventListener()`) runs when the page loads, before the event has been invoked to actually set a value within `deferredPrompt`. You need to re-organise the flow so that the required entities are in the correct state for your logic to be executed. There's not enough context in the question to help you with that

Comment: But the problem is `window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt')`  function is never got executed even after the page load.

Comment: Which browsers are you using? `beforeinstallprompt` is still experimental and doesn't yet have wide support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent#browser_compatibility

Comment: I am using Chrome Android

Comment: The latest version? As support was only added in v117, which was released September 12th https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeinstallprompt

Comment: Yes the latest version.  But I just came up to one article in which I learnt that my application should be hosted on SSL. And we don't have SSL server